# Item values not displaying in Oracle Apex 4.2

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, display

What on earth can cause that in an Oracle Apex 4.2 application, the item values are not displaying (display only, select list and text items), though I can check that they are correctly set in the Session State.
I initialize them in an After Header process, where I insert them into a database table as well, just for the sake of checking, and they appear correctly in the table...
Any idea?

Comment: Could you post *how* you initialized them (code you used, I mean), as well as screenshot which shows how the screen looks like?

Comment: It is simple SQL: select var1,var2 into :P35_VAR1,:P35_VAR2 from mytable where user_id = :P101_USER_ID;

Comment: I tried to simulate what you described, and failed. Though, I did that on Apex 20.1 on apex.oracle.com; I don't have 4.2 any more. If possible, create a demo page there, share credentials and we'll have a look.